# How to define 2 different endpoints for variable path parameter and specific path parameter in swagger

Tags: rest, api, swagger

I want to define 2 rest endpoints:

1. POST on /a/{id}/c
2. POST on /a/b/c

b here being a specific keyword.
The reason I need separate endpoints is payloads are different for both

The problem is when I do a POST on /a/b/c, the request is going to the first and due to mismatch of payloads, failing

Can this be done in swagger?
Is there better way to do this?

Comment: What does /a/{id}/c do different than /a/b/c? It's a good idea to set the endpoints up differently so they wouldn't overlap

Comment: @Lesleyvdp

/system/{userId}/roles adds role to a specific user
/system/batch/roles adds roles to multiple users

What should be different endpoints?

Comment: I have posted an answer with some clarification.

Comment: What server framework are you using? Looks like it's not fully compliant because the [OpenAPI Specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.1.md#patterned-fields) states that *"When matching URLs, concrete (non-templated) paths would be matched before their templated counterparts."* Can you post the server code that does the path matching?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you could create two new POST endpoints and separate their functionality a little. Separating the functionality in the endpoint itself also makes it easier to read and to work with, as it immediately states what the endpoint is there for. Whether it be for a single user, or a whole batch of users, but still performing the same action. For example:

Adding a role to a specific user.

```
POST /system/roles/user/{userid}
```

Adding roles to a batch of users at once.

```
POST /system/roles/batch
```

Would that work for you?

Comment: This seems odd as user is part of system and roles belong to a particular user and the endpoint should be on that lines.
/system/roles/user
This states that roles belong to system and roles have users

Comment: I am unsure about what your setup looks like, but that sounds reasonable. You could and like you say should structure it correctly according to your project's setup. /system/user/roles/batch and /system/user/{userid}/roles would be an option as well.